# Python class read from MySQL and update Background color

Tags: python, pyqt5

i have created a simple window Gui with a single button  with PyQT5 Designer tool
py code :

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'ela.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.15.9
#
# WARNING: Any manual changes made to this file will be lost when pyuic5 is
# run again.  Do not edit this file unless you know what you are doing.


from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(640, 480)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(260, 350, 111, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.pushButton.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("QPushButton { \n"
"background-color: rgb(100, 176, 176);\n"
"border: 5px solid rgb(100, 150, 160);\n"
"border-radius: 10px;\n"
"/*color:white*/\n"
"}\n"
"QPushButton:hover{\n"
"/*background-color: rgb(180, 230, 240);*/\n"
"border: 5px solid rgb(0, 0, 255);\n"
"}")
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 640, 22))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "01"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

i want when i open the window my app reading the database from my server and depending the reading (it would be 0 or 1 or 2    as inputs)  change the background color of the button  .
as an example if reads in the table in the last row in the 3 column  "0"  the background color change to green  and if it reads  "1"  the change to Red

i add a class to the previous code in order to connect and read my database :

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'ela.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.15.9
#
# WARNING: Any manual changes made to this file will be lost when pyuic5 is
# run again.  Do not edit this file unless you know what you are doing.


from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import mysql.connector

class ReadDataBase:
  def __init__(self, Table):
    self.Table = Table
    
    
  pos01 = ""
  pos02 = ""


  def connecting(self):
    mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
      host="192.168.1.110",  # working ok
      user="user",
      password="pass",
      database="Databs"
    )
    mycursor = mydb.cursor()
    # select last row (all colums) from the table
    mycursor.execute("SELECT * FROM" + " " + self.Table + " " +"ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1")
    myresult = mycursor.fetchone()
    # prints the result of the database but it is as a tuple ,
    print(myresult)
    # check and store every possition on the tuple 
    self.pos01 = myresult[2]
    # only if we want to return this parameter and not the others after this command
    #return self.pos01
    self.pos02 = myresult[3]
    # returns all the parameters
    return self.pos02, self.pos01



class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(640, 480)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(260, 350, 111, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.pushButton.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("QPushButton { \n"
"background-color: rgb(100, 176, 176);\n"
"border: 5px solid rgb(100, 150, 160);\n"
"border-radius: 10px;\n"
"/*color:white*/\n"
"}\n"
"QPushButton:hover{\n"
"/*background-color: rgb(180, 230, 240);*/\n"
"border: 5px solid rgb(0, 0, 255);\n"
"}")
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 640, 22))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "01"))


    def checkDatabase():
        ant = ""
        #ant2 = ""
        test = ReadDataBase("YF10")
        test.connecting()
        if test.pos01 == 0:
           ant = test.pos01
           return ant           
        if test.pos01 != 0:
           ant = test.pos01
           return ant  

        #  later button to add
        #if test.pos02 == 0:
        #   ant2 = test.pos02
        #if test.pos02 != 0:
        #   ant2 = test.pos02




if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    Ui_MainWindow.checkDatabase()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

ok it works .. when i run the script i have my window with the button and also in terminal i can get the readings from my last database entry : **(19, datetime.datetime(2023, 3, 27, 15, 34, 24), 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0)  **
where the "19" is the first column entry id  , the next one is the date and the others is what i am looking for to take the readings for my buttons

as a very new user in programing python and in OOP logic  i would like a help how can i pass my "checkDatabase()" method reading to the main class so i can change my PushButton color

thanks in advance

i tried a vary methods to pass the database readings to the main class but with no result (newbie )

Comment: Please consider that warning: "Do not edit this file unless you know what you are doing.". Follow the official guidelines about [using Designer](//www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html), instead of editing pyuic generated files (the same goes for the current answer given below).

Answer (score 0):

To change the background color of the button based on the database reading, you need to modify the setupUi method of the Ui_MainWindow class to read the database using the ReadDataBase class and set the background color of the button accordingly. You can do this by adding the following code to the setupUi method:

```
db = ReadDataBase("your_table_name")
pos1, pos2 = db.connecting()
if pos2 == "0":
   self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("background-color: green;")
elif pos2 == "1":
   self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("background-color: red;")
```

This code first creates an instance of the ReadDataBase class with the name of the table you want to read. Then it calls the connecting method to read the last row of the table and store the values in the pos1 and pos2 variables. Finally, it checks the value of pos2 and sets the background color of the button accordingly.